# Flex hack for authenticated file upload

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, file-upload

Does anyone know the file upload hack for Flex, which will allow files to be uploaded to authenticated web services via multipart form post?  [In this bug report from the Adobe site](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2926796), a user reports:

> Flash isn't cross-browser compatible if this feature only works via
>   Javascript hacks

So far, I've been unable to craft such a hack.  I'm unsure what to do next.  Here's what I've tried so far (all have been unsuccessful or impossible)

- [Set cookies on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841642/set-cookies-in-flex-urlrequest)
- [Pass cookies to Flex URLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841642/set-cookies-in-flex-urlrequest)
- [Create hidden html form in javascript to post file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918445/hidden-form-file-post-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately this is what worked for me.  I modified my web service to accept a stream of bytes instead of a multipart file.  Then, I used `URLLoader` to upload the bytes to the service.

```
private var fileReference:FileReference;

public function loadFile()
{
   fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
   fileReference.load();
}

private function fileLoaded(evt:Event):void{
   fileReference.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
   startUpload();
}

public function startUpload():void {

   var xml:String = // xml to post along with the file ;
   var url:String = // url to the web service

   var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
   bytes.writeUTFBytes(fileReference.name);
   bytes.writeUTFBytes(xml);
   bytes.writeBytes(fileReference.data);
   bytes.position = 0;

   var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
   request.data = bytes;
   request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
   request.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
   urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete);
   urlLoader.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, uploadError);
   urlLoader.load(request);
}

private function uploadComplete(e:Event):void {
   // handle success
}

private function uploadError(e:Event):void {
   // handle failure
}
```